# Do Iron Gauntlets count as an unarmed strike?

Tags: dnd-5e, weapons, monk, unarmed-combat

A pair of Iron Gauntlets add 1d4 Bludgeoning, and Monk characters roll an additional 1d4. This allows you to do 2d4 (+mod) damage at first level, but how would they work in regards to the Monk's ability to make a second unarmed strike in an action? Do the gauntlets still count as an unarmed strike, allowing you to do possibly two sets of 2d4+Mod in one turn at first level?

Comment: When you say Iron Gauntlets, are you referencing a specific item? If so, which book does it come from?

Answer (score 2):

Theoretically you could, but Iron Gauntlets would need to be monks weapons for the PC's monastery.

"You gain the following benefits while you are unarmed or wielding only monk weapons and you aren't wearing armor or wielding a shield"

If they were, however, they wouldn't stack as "You can roll a d4 in place of the normal damage of your unarmed strike or monk weapon."

Comment: This answer would be improved, I think, if it stated whether Iron Guantlets are or are not monk weapons.

Comment: That unfortunately isn't cut and dry. Iron Gauntlets are homebrew and classed as simple weapons which means they could be monk weapons. But if homebrew is being used, the rules are already listed: https://www.dandwiki.com/wiki/Iron_Gauntlets_(5e_Equipment)